# Where my mistake in converting jquery ajax to pure js ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

That's my **JQuery** code which is currently working ->

```
$("#newsLetter-form").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        email = $('#emailId').val();
        console.log(email);
        $.ajax({
          url: '/subscribes/emailSubscribe',
          type:'POST',

          data:{
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            email:email,
          },
          success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $('#responseFromSub').text("Registred!");
            $('#responseFromSub').css('background','lightgreen')
            $('#newsLetter-form').css('display','none');
            $('.sucsessMessage').fadeIn(1);
            setTimeout(function(){$('.sucsessMessage').fadeOut(1);$('#newsLetter-form').css('display','flex');},3000);
          },
          error:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            var val = 'asdasd:111122:123123123';
            var response1 = response.responseJSON.message.substring(response.responseJSON.message.indexOf("\"title\":"));
            response1 = response1.split(":").pop();
            response1 = response1.split(',')[0];
            response1 = response1.replace("\"", "");
            response1 = response1.replace("\"", "");
            console.log(response1);
            $('#responseFromSub').text(response1);
            $('#responseFromSub').css('background','red');
            $('#newsLetter-form').css('display','none');
            $('.sucsessMessage').fadeIn(1);
            setTimeout(function(){$('.sucsessMessage').fadeOut(1);$('#newsLetter-form').css('display','flex');},3000);
          },
         });
    });
```

And this is my converted code which isn't working, **it says 400 bad request wrong data**. I'm using laravel and mailchimp for newsletter with jquery everything is working but with this **pure js** code, no ->

```
                function myFunc123() {
        var email1 = document.getElementById("emailId").value;
        alert(email1);
        var data = {
        "_token": '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        email: email1
    };
        var boundary = String(Math.random()).slice(2);
        var boundaryMiddle = '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
        var boundaryLast = '--' + boundary + '--\r\n'
        var body = ['\r\n'];
        for (var key in data) {
        body.push('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' + key + '"\r\n\r\n' + data[key] + '\r\n');
    }
        body = body.join(boundaryMiddle) + boundaryLast;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/subscribes/emailSubscribe', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState != 4) return;
        alert(this.responseText);
    }
        xhr.send(body);
    }
```

I fixed it the problem was here ->

```
var email1 = document.getElementById("emailId").value;
        alert(email1);
        var data = {
        "_token": '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        email: email1
```

Now it's working..

**BUT** the page is refreshing after request how can I disable refreshing ?

Comment: "BUT the page is refreshing after request how can I disable refreshing ?" Just like you do in the jQuery code....

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `event.preventDefault()`, which was in the jQuery code. The default behaviour is to refresh the page on submit (which is a very dumb default), you want to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, final converted version looks like that.

```
 var ele = document.getElementById("newsLetter-form");
    ele.addEventListener("submit", handleEmail, false);
    function handleEmail(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var email1 = document.getElementById("emailId").value;
        var data = {
            "_token": '{{ csrf_token() }}',
            email: email1
        };
        var boundary = String(Math.random()).slice(2);
        var boundaryMiddle = '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
        var boundaryLast = '--' + boundary + '--\r\n'
        var body = ['\r\n'];
        for (var key in data) {
            body.push('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' + key + '"\r\n\r\n' + data[key] + '\r\n');
        }
        body = body.join(boundaryMiddle) + boundaryLast;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/subscribes/emailSubscribe', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(xhr.status===200)
            {
                document.getElementById("responseFromSub").innerHTML="Registered";
                document.getElementById("responseFromSub").style.background="lightgreen";
                document.getElementById("newsLetter-form").style.display="none";
                document.getElementsByClassName("sucsessMessage")[0].style.display="block";
                setTimeout(function () {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("sucsessMessage")[0].style.display="none";
                    document.getElementById("newsLetter-form").style.display="flex";
                }, 3000);
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("responseFromSub").innerHTML="Something goes wrong..";
                document.getElementById("responseFromSub").style.background="red";
                document.getElementById("newsLetter-form").style.display="none";
                document.getElementsByClassName("sucsessMessage")[0].style.display="block";
                setTimeout(function () {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("sucsessMessage")[0].style.display="none";
                    document.getElementById("newsLetter-form").style.display="flex";
                }, 3000);
            }
        }
        xhr.send(body);
    }
```